# Space around not working in flex box in CSS

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I am trying to build a features section of a page with two rows and two columns for each rows using flex. I have linked the expected result and my actual output below. I have also attached my coding snippets.

Sorry, if this seems very simple and dumb. I am self learning and For the first time ever I am building a page without any guidance from anyone.

**Expected output:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dofr7.jpg
**Actual output**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmV7v.png

I tried `transform` property to make it center but it doesn't seem right option to this simple problem. Sorry if this sounds dumb.

**HTML:**

```
<section class="flexbox">

            <div class="left-side column">
               <div class="one column-container">
                <img class="feature-img" src="images/icon-access-anywhere.svg" alt="icon 1">
                <h3>
                    Access your files, anywhere
                </h3>
                <p class="features-para">  The ability to use a smartphone, tablet, or computer to access your account means your 
                    files follow you everywhere</p>
               </div>
               <div class="two column-container">
                <img class="feature-img" src="images/icon-security.svg" alt="icon 2">
                <h3>
                    Security you can trust
                </h3>
                <p class="features-para">2-factor authentication and user-controlled encryption are just a couple of the security 
                    features we allow to help secure your files.</p>

               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="right-side column">
                <div class="three column-container">
                    <img class="feature-img" src="images/icon-collaboration.svg" alt="icon 3">
                    <h3>
                    Real-time collaboration
                </h3>
                <p class="features-para">Securely share files and folders with friends, family and colleagues for live collaboration. 
                    No email attachments required.</p>
            </div>
                <div class="four column-container">
                    <img class="feature-img" src="images/icon-any-file.svg" alt="icon 4">
                    <h3>
                        Store any type of file
                    </h3>
                    <p class="features-para">  Whether you're sharing holidays photos or work documents, Fylo has you covered allowing for all 
                        file types to be securely stored and shared.</p>
                </div>

            </div>


    </section>
```

**CSS:**

```
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if your snippet actually contains all relevant details of the problematic situation, but if you add a `max-width` to `.column` (adjust value as desired) and `text-align: center;` to all of its children (using `.column *` as a selector) , it displays as desired:

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 240px;
  
}
.column * {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="flexbox">

  <div class="left-side column">
    <div class="one column-container">
      <img class="feature-img" src="images/icon-access-anywhere.svg" alt="icon 1">
      <h3>
        Access your files, anywhere
      </h3>
      <p class="features-para"> The ability to use a smartphone, tablet, or computer to access your account means your files follow you everywhere</p>
    </div>
    <div class="two column-container">
      <img class="feature-img" src="images/icon-security.svg" alt="icon 2">
      <h3>
        Security you can trust
      </h3>
      <p class="features-para">2-factor authentication and user-controlled encryption are just a couple of the security features we allow to help secure your files.</p>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-side column">
    <div class="three column-container">
      <img class="feature-img" src="images/icon-collaboration.svg" alt="icon 3">
      <h3>
        Real-time collaboration
      </h3>
      <p class="features-para">Securely share files and folders with friends, family and colleagues for live collaboration. No email attachments required.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="four column-container">
      <img class="feature-img" src="images/icon-any-file.svg" alt="icon 4">
      <h3>
        Store any type of file
      </h3>
      <p class="features-para"> Whether you're sharing holidays photos or work documents, Fylo has you covered allowing for all file types to be securely stored and shared.</p>
    </div>

  </div>


</section>
```

Comment: Thanks alot man. It worked now. Not sure if this is the right place to ask this. I am trying to learn front end at this moment. I know the basic concepts, but when I code still I am getting so many silly doubts. How should I learn and master my CSS skills?

Comment: That's a very generic question... "CSS-Tricks" is a good place to look,  some of the more basic articles are here: https://css-tricks.com/guides/beginner/ BTW: If my answer helped you, please mark it as accepted or/and give it an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this situation by centering the `margin: 0 auto` and setting the specific width of the container (in the snippet that example with `600px`). In the future, this container can be used for other blocks and modified using media queries.

```css
.flexbox {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<section class="flexbox">
  <div class="left-side column">
    <div class="one column-container">
      <img class="feature-img" src="images/icon-access-anywhere.svg" alt="icon 1">
      <h3>
        Access your files, anywhere
      </h3>
      <p class="features-para"> The ability to use a smartphone, tablet, or computer to access your account means your
        files follow you everywhere</p>
    </div>
    <div class="two column-container">
      <img class="feature-img" src="images/icon-security.svg" alt="icon 2">
      <h3>
        Security you can trust
      </h3>
      <p class="features-para">2-factor authentication and user-controlled encryption are just a couple of the security
        features we allow to help secure your files.</p>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-side column">
    <div class="three column-container">
      <img class="feature-img" src="images/icon-collaboration.svg" alt="icon 3">
      <h3>
        Real-time collaboration
      </h3>
      <p class="features-para">Securely share files and folders with friends, family and colleagues for live collaboration.
        No email attachments required.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="four column-container">
      <img class="feature-img" src="images/icon-any-file.svg" alt="icon 4">
      <h3>
        Store any type of file
      </h3>
      <p class="features-para"> Whether you're sharing holidays photos or work documents, Fylo has you covered allowing for all
        file types to be securely stored and shared.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```